# How can I group components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Problem

I need help to understand where I put my `aside` code. 
The goal of him is rendered components like `searchInput` and `menuStudy`,

I'm thinking put in `container's` folder, but he does not have any logical objective like request or anything else, he only group and render these containers (SeachInputContainer and MenuStudyContainer).

What do you think if I put this in AsideContainer and call these containers?

## Example

**AsideContainer.jsx**

```
[ ... ]
const Aside = () => (
  <aside className="w-1/4">
    <SearchInputContainer />
    <MenuStudyContainer />
  </aside>
);
[ ... ]
```

And in my App.jsx I just called this container to get All aside.

**App.jsx**

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap">
    <Aside /> // all aside componentes live here.
    <div className="w-3/4 pl-8">
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

This makes sense?

## Folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "wrapper", more than a "container", in fact it does not fetch data or manage child's props through its state.
A "wrapper" could be considered as a presentational component or a HoC if you want to implement it so it could wrap other components too.

Comment: Nice, so I would have a component which calls the SearchInputContainer and MenuStudyContainer right? It makes sense =D